Spring Unit testing Controller java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.productIdList" expected:<[1, 2]> but was:<null>
I got controller endpoint that creates Order with specific List of Products. As post method it gets  OrderUpdateDto that has List productIdList which during a method execute it checks in repository for specific objects. During tests with Postman everything is working but unit testing.
What I am missing? For below test scenario got:
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.productIdList" expected:<[1, 2]> but was:<null> Expected :[1, 2] Actual   :null
OrderServiceImpl

@Service
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService {

    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Autowired
    public OrderServiceImpl(OrderRepository orderRepository, ProductRepository productRepository) {
        this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
    }

 @Override
    public OrderDto createOrder(OrderUpdateDto orderUpdateDto) {
        Order order = new Order();
        order.setStatus(OrderStatus.CREATED);
        List<Product> productListByIdList = getProductListByIdList(orderUpdateDto.getProductIdList());
        order.setProducts(productListByIdList);
        order.setPrice(order.calculateTotalPrice());
        Order saved = orderRepository.save(order);
        return mapToDto(saved);
    }

 public List<Product> getProductListByIdList(List<Long> productIds) {
        List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (long productId : productIds) {
            Product product = productRepository.findById(productId)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException(EntityNotFoundException.PRODUCT_NOT_FOUND_BY_ID, String.valueOf(productId)));
            productList.add(product);
        }
        return productList;
    }

 public List<Long> getIdListFromProductList(List<Product> products) {
        return products.stream()
                .map(Product::getId)
                .toList();
    }

    private OrderDto mapToDto(Order order) {
        OrderDto orderDto = new OrderDto();
        orderDto.setId(order.getId());
        orderDto.setStatus(order.getStatus());
        List<Long> productsIdList = getIdListFromProductList(order.getProducts());
        orderDto.setProductIdList(productsIdList);
        orderDto.setPrice(order.getPrice());
        return orderDto;
    }
}

OrderControllerUnitTests
@WebMvcTest(OrderController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class OrderControllerUnitTest {
    public static final String API_ORDERS = "/api/orders";
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private OrderService orderService;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;


    @Test
    public void OrderController_CreateOrder_ReturnCreated() throws Exception {

        OrderStatus orderStatus = OrderStatus.CREATED;
        List<Long> productIdList = Arrays.asList(1L, 2L);
        BigDecimal price=BigDecimal.valueOf(10.99);

        OrderUpdateDto orderUpdateDto = OrderUpdateDto.builder()
                .status(orderStatus)
                .productIdList(productIdList)
                .build();
        OrderDto expectedOrderDto = OrderDto.builder()
                .id(1L)
                .price(price)
                .productIdList(productIdList)
                .status(orderStatus)
                .build();

        given(orderService.createOrder(any(OrderUpdateDto.class))).willReturn(expectedOrderDto);


        String orderUpdateDtoJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(orderUpdateDto);

        mockMvc.perform(post(API_ORDERS)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(orderUpdateDtoJson))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").value(1L))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.status").value(orderStatus.name()))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.productIdList").value(productIdList))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.price").value(price));
    }

OrderUpdateDto
@Builder
@Data
public class OrderUpdateDto {

    private OrderStatus status;
    private List<Long> productIdList;

}

OrderDto
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
public class OrderDto {

    private Long id;
    private OrderStatus status;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private List<Long> productIdList;

}

I tried changing @Data to @Getter and @Setter (some other post) but then got different errors.
